# How to combine two text formatting commands into one?

Tags: text-processing, sed, command-line, command, text-formatting

How does one combine two commands like the ones shown below into one command with one output file?

*first command:*

```
printf '%s\n' {001..500} input > output
```

*second command:*

```
sed 's/^/PREFIX /; s/$/ SUFFIX/' input > output
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realise you've answered your question, but a simpler solution would be to put the prefix and suffix in the `printf` command.

```
printf 'PREFIX %s SUFFIX\n' {001..500} > output
```

(I'm not sure if the `input` part should be there. It's absent in your answer.)

Comment: Oh even better! Awesome, thanks! 

p.s. You just taught me something... :)

Comment: How come the sed command changed to look more simple? How is that possible? Is that like printf's equivalent?

Comment: The `sed` command replaces the beginning `^` and end `$` of each line. `printf` defines how it will "print" the numbers, i.e. each line consist of `PREFIX ` followed by a string `%s`, then ` SUFFIX` and a newline `\n`. The numbers expanded from `{001..500}` replace the string placeholder `%s`.

Comment: because it doesn't actually need the input, it works fine without.

Comment: Regarding `input`, if this is present, the command will create another line after the numbers, but with the literal string `input` instead. (I'm presuming you don't want this.)

Comment: Wait I'm totally confused. Is that printf's version of the same sed command for PREFIX and SUFFIX?

Comment: They are the equivalent in *function*, but not in how they work. `sed` does a search and replace. `printf` prints the argument(s) in a certain format. Have a search for both commands, and read some tutorials. They are both useful commands, but quite different.

Comment: I meant are they equivalent in the meaning that they have the same outputted results? p.s. you are wayyyyyyyyyy too smart. lol :)

Comment: They are the equivalent in output, but the way they function is different.

Comment: Gotcha! I actually was asking how to combine my two commands sed & printf, but you chose to do it only with printf, right? Okay, that's cool. But just out of curiosity how would I combine my original two commands? Did I do it right? Or is there a simpler way?

Comment: Yes, I would have combined them as you did.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!

Both commands as one:

```
printf '%s\n' {001..500} | sed 's/^/PREFIX /; s/$/ SUFFIX/' > output
```

Comment: Simpler: `printf 'PREFIX %s SUFFIX\n' {001..500} >output`